# Modifying Existing Mujoco Environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, mujoco

I wish to add a block in an existing mujoco environment, for eg in half cheetah. Can anyone guide as to how the xml file is to be modified for achieving this?

Comment: Could you add more information about what exactly you want to modify in the XML files? The documentations in Mujoco is not really good.

Comment: I wish to add a cuboidal box with a certain dimension at a certain position in an existing environment such as hopper.